# edit 2500 text files to add three decimal places for integer number and decimal number where you can find after @x*

Tags: batch-file

there are 2500 text files to check and ammend teh decimal places of number where in after @x*.

example:

```
@x*1 pcs (result should be @x*1.000 pcs)
@x*1.2 pcs (result should be @x*1.200 pcs)
@x*1.25 pcs (result should be @x*1.250 pcs)
@x*1.238 pcs (result should be @x*1.238 pcs)
@x*1.2897 pcs (result should be @x*1.299 pcs)

enter code here
```

Comment: instead of `enter code here` you shoud enter your code here.

Comment: If I assume your post has the original input text, what do you want the output text to look like? Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: Why 1.2897 is rounded to 1.299? Shouldn't it be 1.290?

Comment: yes Aacini, it hould be 1.290.

Answer (score 0):

Simple using the [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) regular expression text processing utility, coupled with a bit of custom JScript. I used a method described at http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ to reliably round decimal values. Without it, a value like 0.0008 would improperly round to 0.000.

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.txt) do call jrepl "(@x\*)(\d+\.?\d*|\.d+)" "$1+Number(Math.round($2+'e'+3)+'e-'+3).toFixed(3)" /j /f "%%F" /o -
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process the 2500 text files
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
   rem Process this file:                 load it, then delete it
   for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=. " %%a in ('type "%%f" ^& del "%%f"') do (
      rem Get current decimal part
      if "%%c" equ "" (set b=0000) else set "b=%%b000"
      rem Round it to three digits
      set /A b=1!b:~0,4!+5
      rem And write it
      echo %%a.!b:~1,3! pcs>> "%%f"
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: *Example added*

```
C:\> type test.txt
@x*1 pcs
@x*1.2 pcs
@x*1.25 pcs
@x*1.238 pcs
@x*1.2897 pcs

C:\> test.bat

C:\> type test.txt
@x*1.000 pcs
@x*1.200 pcs
@x*1.250 pcs
@x*1.238 pcs
@x*1.290 pcs
```

Comment: I tested this codes. There is a issue in this code, which i can not solve. I want to edit only numbers after "@x*" only. There should not be any effect on other numbers. I am waiting help from you all.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your concern. See the edit in my answer: both the data and the result are _exactly the same_ that you posted in your question!

Comment: this is the file I want to edit.  there you can see @x* and after that number. I want to edit only those numbers.

     MATERIAL      : SLL040083, STEAMED BEECHWOOD 32X 40X 830 MMS. @X*0.0161 PCS
                                OR @X*0.0134 MS. - 62 PIECES EACH.

     RIPPING       : WIDTH : 18    MMS. AMOUNT NEEDED FOR THIS ORDER: @X*0.0268 MS.
     MULTIBLADE      THICK : AS PLANED 32 MMS.
     SAW

     MOULDING      : WIDTH : 25    MMS. AMOUNT NEEDED FOR THIS ORDER: @X*0.0268 MS.
     FOUR-SIDED      THICK : 14    MMS.